# How can I set up an automatic check for supervision (monitoring of services) on Ubuntu 12.04 with ps?

Tags: ps

I'm setting up a supervision on an Ubuntu 12.04 server.
One of the checks is supposed to make sure some processes are properly running.

Basically it runs a `ps -aux` and checks if a given process is there.

Unfortunately, on Ubuntu `ps` will only show processes for the current user. My supervision system does not run - of course - as the root user.

Is there any way to achieve this?

(except setting up a cron job as root, dumping `ps -aux` on a temporary file :D)

**EDIT**

Actually the problem only happens on a 12.04 box (`ps -aux` is working as expected on 14.04).

Is there anyway to fix this behavior?
The server will be upgraded soon, but summer holidays are not the best time for that :)

Comment: Supervision as in watching what other users are doing...? You need root for that generally....

Comment: Or you could run w

Comment: Supervision as "making sure postgresql, nfsd, etc. are properly running" ;)

Comment: hm, `ps -aux' shows others users processes for me on 15.04. 
also, could I suggest that instead of reinventing the wheel, there are a number of existing solutions for what you are trying to achieve, e.g.: https://mmonit.com/monit/

Comment: Ok.. I just realized "ps -aux" does not list all processes on a 12.04 box, it's working fine on the 14 one.  Actually I'm not reinventing anything, this is for a nagios setup ;)

Comment: @Noth ah, fair enough :) I don't have a 12.04 setup to test on, but maybe as a workaround you can check directly in /proc?
find /proc -name status -exec grep "Name:" {} \; 2>/dev/null
Is the box hardened, maybe running selinux?

Comment: Isn't service (or sysctl) status for this?

Comment: There's a bug I think for PPTP but other that that service (service name) status should yield more proper results.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so ... !

This "process sandbox feature" seems to happen only on 12.04.

One way to bypass this is to allow the expected user to run `ps` as sudo:

Edit `/etc/sudoers` :

```
accountname ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/ps
```

Then use `sudo ps -aux` instead of `ps -aux`.